# Find a parameter value based on weight of a portfolio

Tags: r

I am trying to find the value of a parameter where all constituents of a portfolio with a parameter smaller than this value sum up to 25% of the entire portfolio.

Of course, using R.

For example, I have having a portfolio for a market index that's having 100 constituent equity securities. 25% of this portfolio means 25% of total market value. I want to find the value of a parameter, let's say the P/E ratio, that all securities with a P/E ratio smaller than such value contribute to 25% of this portfolio's market value.

i know that I can use 'quantile' function to find the 25% value for P/E ratio,

```
Bottom_Quartile <- data[(data$PE < quantile(data$PE,0.25),]
```

But that value not necessarily corresponding to 25% market value, and result generated above is not giving out a total market value = 25% of Original total market value.

I am wondering if there is a function that can help us find the value of a specific parameter (in this case P/E ratio) based on the given quantile of another parameter (in this case 25% Market Value).

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

All right, here is an update.
I have tried some method to do this the following one worked fine, however, it looks very inefficient.

```
#compute % market weight first
data$MarketValuePct <- data$MarketValue / sum(data$MarketValue)
#sort the result by descend order of P/E
sort_data <- data[order(data$PE),]
#calculate cumulative sum for percentage market value
sort_data$cumsum_MarketValuePct <- cumsum(sort_data$MarketValuePct)
#Locate the edge of bottom quartile
Bottom_quartile <- sort_data[sort_data$cumsum_MarketValuePct < 0.25, ]
#The bottom value of PE is what I was looking for 
4th_Qartile_PE <- Bottom_quartile [nrow(Bottom_quartile),(col# of PE)]
```

I am still looking for a more elegant and more accurate way of doing this. Please kindly help if you have any idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do not want a quantile of the market value, but 25% of the total market value.
You can use `order` to sort the stocks by increasing PE, and `cumsum` to compute
the total market value of stocks below a certain PE.

```
i <- order(PE)
tail( which( cumsum(MCap[i]) < .25 * sum(MCap) ), 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! This is exactly what i have did, but I am wondering if there is an more elegant and accurate way to do this.